# MySQL - Sum values width same ID in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I want sum values into my database by the same ID in the same table.
Table in database:

```
| ID | Value_o | Value_t | Value_tt |
|  1 |   40    |    20   |   10     |
```

query:

```
SELECT SUM(Value_o) AS Value_o, SUM(Value_t) AS Value_t, SUM(Value_tt) AS Value_TT 
WHERE ID IN(1, 1)
```

And now the output id:

```
| Value_o | Value_t | Value_tt |
|   40    |    20   |   10     |
```

but I want:

```
| Value_o | Value_t | Value_tt |
|   80    |    40   |   20     |
```

I want get this output without JOIN.

Thanks!

PS. Sorry for my bad eng :/

Comment: "but I want:" --- how does it correlate with data in the table?

Comment: Can you explain the logic?  It looks like you just want to multiply each column by 2, but can you confirm?

Comment: can you give us some more infos have you tried something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Value_o) AS Value_o, 
  SUM(Value_t) AS Value_t, 
  SUM(Value_tt) AS Value_TT 
FROM
  (
  SELECT ID, Value_o, Value_t, Value_tt FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ID, Value_o, Value_t, Value_tt FROM Table1
  ) Table2 
WHERE ID IN(1, 1);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65821/4)

Comment: What I should to change if I want add: IN(1, 1, 1) ?? Now it's not working, only if I add (1, 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Value_o) AS Value_o, SUM(Value_t) AS Value_t, SUM(Value_tt) AS Value_TT 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING ID = 1
```

Comment: Then tell us how you want 80 40 20 to come out, how do you get that.

Comment: For me it's working. Next time formulate more clearly what you want to achieve! http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9830/3/0

Comment: @Wawrzyniec I think you are missing a `FROM` clause in your answer.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for pointing this out, first line has been just copy from a question :/. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL [`in`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator doesn't work this way. Even if you have a value multiple times in the set, it doesn't duplicate the rows of your result.

If you want to have all the rows multiple times, you must use [`union all`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) and sum over that

```
SELECT SUM(Value_o) AS Value_o, SUM(Value_t) AS Value_t, SUM(Value_tt) AS Value_TT 
from (select * from mytable union all select * from mytable) t
WHERE ID IN (1)
```